# How to call a method with different objects as parameter types

Tags: c#, object, parameters

I have multiple objects with similar properties. The objects are stored in dictionaries. Now I want one single Method to work with all dictionaries.

I tried making them child elements of another object. Using the parent object as parameter and calling the function with their child objects was not working for me.

`ArticleItem.cs`:

```
public class ArticleItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    ... constructor and so on...
}
```

`ArticleItemB.cs`:

```
public class ArticleItemB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string AnotherText { get; set; }

... constructor and so on...
}
```

`Programm.cs`:

```
public Dictionary<string, ArticleItem> newArticle_Catalog = new 
Dictionary<string, ArticleItem>();

public Dictionary<string, ArticleItemB> newArticleB_Catalog = new 
Dictionary<string, ArticleItemB>();


newArticle_Catalog.Add("1", new ArticleItem(1,"ABC"));
newArticle_Catalog.Add("2", new ArticleItem(2,"DEF"));

newArticleB_Catalog.Add("1", new ArticleItemB(1,"ABC","DEF"));
newArticleB_Catalog.Add("2", new ArticleItemB(2,"GHI","JKL"));


public void PrintCatalog(Dictionary<string, OBJECTTYPE> catalog)
{
    foreach (var item in newCatalog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.value.ToString());
    }
}
```

I want to call `PrintCatalog()` either like:

`PrintCatalog(newArticle_Catalog);`

or like:

`PrintCatalog(newArticleB_Catalog);`

And get their `.ToString()` printed out

Comment: Although it would work with a Dictionary<string,object> as object provides a ToString()-method, it probably would be more appropriate if you use an interface or base class that also contains the shared primary key ID.

Comment: use `object` as an object if you want to use only .ToString() method

Comment: The classes have more than the .ToString() method.
I already made them child objects of a base class but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a common base class as:

```
public abstract class ArticleItemBase
{ }
```

and let your classes inherit from it as:

```
public class ArticleItem : ArticleItemBase
```

and

```
public class ArticleItemB : ArticleItemBase
```

You can then make your `PrintCatalog` accept a Dictionary with a generic value type and restrict it to only objects that are of your base class:

```
public static void PrintCatalog<T>(Dictionary<string, T> catalog) where T : ArticleItemBase
{
    foreach (var item in catalog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I call PrintCatalog() from another class?

Comment: If you leave it static as in my example, just use [NameOfTheClass].PrintCatalog(catalog). If not, create an instance of the class and call it by instance.PrintCatalog(catalog).

Answer (score 2):

Create a base Class that has these properties and inherit the base class from all Item classes.
Then in PrintCatalog just take parameter of type base class rather than each item